# How can I execute Javascript on already loaded webpage in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I want to execute a javascript on already loaded webpage in Webview. I
am loading a new article webpage eg: www.techcrunch,com in webview. I
want to run javascript on this already loaded webpage in Webview. This
javascript is an external file in assets folder. The javascript
basically extracts images from the  tags in does some other
processing in the html page. How can I execute this javascript on the
already loaded www.techcrunch.com page?

Thanks,

Comment: I've never done any Android development, but I'm pretty confident there's no way to inject your own scripts into someone else's document in a Webview. That would be an ENORMOUS security problem. You're basically talking about a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack - regardless of the fact that your intentions aren't malicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same like for any other web browser. Use the *javascript* protocol:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Example');");
```